# file_put_contents causes page to refresh

Tags: php, ajax, file-put-contents

I am calling a `file_put_contents()` inside of a PHP script that is executed via AJAX. Whenever I execute this script the client page gets reloaded which is not desirable. Is there a way to prevent the PHP script from reloading the page?

I have tried modifying the headers using the following and passing it as the context parameter in the `file_put_contents` function:

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'follow_location' => false
        )
    )
  );
```

Comment: Unless you're explicitly including some JavaScript in your Ajax response that causes a reload or redirect, it's almost certain that your problem is elsewhere. Maybe your Ajax call is being triggered by a browser event that you are allowing to bubble up?

Comment: @GregSchmidt when I remove the file_put_contents call the problem is resolved. Do you think there is something behind the scenes that is causing a redirect back to the parent script once the actions have been performed with the file?

Comment: There's nowhere near enough information here to make any kind of suggestion on that. Show us the HTML that calls the Ajax, and the code that calls `file_put_contents`.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I am talking more in terms of the behind the scenes of the file_put_contents function itself. Not my code in particular

Comment: `file_put_contents` simply writes output to a file. An Ajax request that generates plain HTML output cannot cause a redirect. The problem will be somewhere in your initial HTML / JavaScript or else in the content that you are putting to the file. Without seeing any of this, we can only make wild guesses.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Ok I have found out some additional info. When commenting out the AJAX return code nothing happens so it isn't on the client side. When commenting out the file_put_contents the problem is fixed. However, the only FPC call that is causing problems is one where I create an HTML file. The other call creates a JSON file and does not cause any issues with respect to redirection.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I have fixed the issue by saving both files as .txt. There was no real necessary reason for me to store them in any other extension. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and my files are .txt. Any solution to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try runnning script in incognito mode. Had same problem with file_put_contents(), and it was live reload VSCode extension that for some reason was refreshing the page.